# How to handle empty values in multi parameter SSRS field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to modify a report that uses a multi value parameter (a|b|c|d). That parameter is split into multiple columns. The expression on the first column is `=Split(Fields!AlternateVendorDetails.Value.ToString(),"|")(0)`. If that field is blank in the query, the field in the column is blank, which is right. However, the other columns evaluate to an error (`=Split(Fields!AlternateVendorDetails.Value.ToString(),"|")(1)`). I've tried `=IIF(Fields!AlternateVendorDetails.Value.ToString()='','',Split(Fields!AlternateVendorDetails.Value.ToString(),"|")(1))`, and I'm not sure what else will work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your report layout and some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS evaluates expressions even when using Iif conditions and that causes the error.

You need custom code to overcome the limitation.

You can create a function that takes the string, the delimiter and array item index, and returns the value if string is not empty and value index exists

```
Public Function GetArrayItem( s As String, d As String, i As Integer) As String

If s = "" Or Split(s, d).Length < i+1 Then 
   Return Nothing
Else
   Return Split(s, d)(i)
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a COALESCE(value1 | value2 | value3,' | | ') in the query. That created the necessary fillers to set the values to blank.